# What is the dead time in between two subsequent outputs in the CD4017 counter?

Tags: timing-analysis

I would like to find out the dead time between subsequent outputs in a cd4017 counter set up in astable mode.I unfortunately do not have a scope to run an experiment myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "dead time"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "astable mode"? Maybe link to the datasheet you are reading that says the CD4017 has either of these things?

Comment: The time between subsequent high outputs...e.g between output 0 and 1, how much time does it take for output 1 to become "high" after output 0 becomes "low"

Comment: It is known as "rise time" and "fall time" in common terms. Or a "transition time" as referred in the datasheet. So read it.

Comment: Here's the datasheet from TI. http://www.google.co.zw/url?q=http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf&sa=U&ved=0CBAQFjAAahUKEwjLoZqw593HAhXMWxQKHUfjB8c&sig2=MRouPz8Db_buKt6NlBHRzQ&usg=AFQjCNHq34R2RSFrFxrtY7LmWfnByPMlrQ

Comment: @EugeneSh. I must have caught on to "dead time somewhere....But i found this though www.thefreedictionary.com/dead+time

Comment: Some circuits have "dead time" between outputs. The question is why you think CD4017 should have it. I don't see anything in the datasheet that says it does.

Comment: My application requires that the time interval between outputs be minimal or completely non existent..I assumed there would be some sort of delay in how the IC progresses from one output to the next because of inefficiencies or by design

Comment: "Minimal" has no meaning in this context and just introduces confusion. A better method of quantifying what you want would be to post a timing diagram. A schematic would also be nice so we can see what you're up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Timing Diagram in the Datasheet shows there is a slight delay as each output changes, so Q1 will be high for a fraction of a second before Q0 is low. In practical terms they are instantaneously done.

[image]

From the Datasheet, the longest possible Low to High or High to Low transition time is 650 nano seconds @ 5V.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such thing as the 4017 operating in astable mode since it's a counter, not an oscillator or a multivibrator.
2. "Dead time" as applied to a 4017 is nonsensical.

Referring to the data sheet excerpt included below, there are two characteristics, \$t_{PLH}\$ and \$t_{PHL}\$ which define how long it takes for a low output to go high (\$t_{PLH}\$) and how long it takes for a high output to go low (\$t_{PHL}\$) once the clock is asserted. Take particular notice that there's no guarantee that any high output will go low before any low output goes high, and vice versa.

As an example of how dead time is nonsensical here, consider the case  where Q0 is high and Q1 is low at the instant the clock goes high.

Then, if \$t_{PLH}\$ for Q1 is 325 nanoseconds and \$t_{PHL}\$ is 650 nanoseconds for Q0, Q1 will go high 325ns before Q0 goes low, so they'll both be high for 325ns.

[image]

Comment: Although the manufacturer didn't do so in this case, there are some other cases where manufacturers will guarantee that evens triggered by the same clock edge will happen in a particular sequence.  Many applications benefit from using level-sensitive rather than edge-triggered clocks, but they need to guarantee that distinct clock outputs will never overlap.  The 4017 does not offer suitable guarantees, but it doesn't mean the concept is "nonsensical".

Comment: @supercat: Since this case involves only the 4017,  I fail to see where other cases involving other devices are relevant.  Moreover, since my statement that: ""Dead time" as applied to a 4017 is nonsensical." clearly referred specifically to the 4017, I also fail to see how you could have construed its meaning as being global.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there are some 4017 chips which, will, in *in practice*, produce outputs which don't overlap.  Further, some manufacturers offer timing guarantees which are more precisely specified than required by industry standard, so it may be that some manufacturer's 4017 chip might be specified to not have dead time.  In any case, a proper response would be that for the indicated part the dead time could range from -170ns to +170ns for the higher speed parts, or -530ns to +530ns for the faster ones.

Comment: In all fairness, that's all just gobbledygook since rather than just voicing opinion, it would be nice if you'd identify the chips which exhibit no overlap. In the same vein, it's not important to identify the manufacturers whose chips don't have dead time, since that's what we're trying to avoid. Interestingly, your intimation that a proper response should include responses which occur before the edge of the clock seem to indicate that you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: What do you mean "before the edge of the clock".  If the falling edge of the active output happens precisely at the clock, and the rising edge of the other happens 530ns later, that would be a dead time of +530ns.  If the rising edge is immediate and the falling edge is 530ns after the clock, that would be a dead time of -530ns.  The negative dead time would be important if one were to insert a delay before the second output in an effort to ensure a certain minimum dead time; if one needs 250ns dead time, one would need a delay of 780ns to ensure that [assuming worst-case behavior].

Comment: I don't know why more parts don't specify relative delays, since in many scenarios there's a huge difference between the amount of circuitry necessary to yield a design that will work under worst-case combination of part behaviors meeting spec, versus the amount required to yield a design that will work under any probable combination of behaviors [even something like wiring an inverting output of a flop back to an input so as to form a divide-by-two is often not guaranteed to work by any timing spec if e.g. min propagation time is 0 and required hold time is 20ns].

Comment: @supercat: The problem I have with expressing negative dead time as a negative number is that it implies that if the high-going edge coincides with the clock, then the low-going edge must have occurred before the clock, when in truth it's just propagation delay after the clock that's the cause.  I find it much less confusing to refer to negative gate time as a positive quantity since time flows in only one direction and what's really being talked about is how long it takes for a second already positive output to go negative once the first has gone positive.

Comment: A positive dead time of t nanoseconds would imply that for the rising edge follows the clock by less than t nanoseconds, the negative edge would have to precede it (which can't happen).  A negative dead time of -t nanoseconds would imply that for the falling edge to follow the clock by less than t nanoseconds, the rising edge would need to precede it.  Since neither edge can precede the clock, a positive dead time of t would imply that the the rising edge must be delayed by at least t nanoseconds, and a negative dead time of -t would imply that the falling edge must be delayed by at least t.

Comment: When discussing the timing relationship between an input and an output, it generally only makes sense to use positive time values.  But when comparing inputs to inputs, or outputs to outputs, signed values make sense.

Comment: supercat: Aarghh... Just More gobbledygook. Most parts' delays are specified relative to a clock edge, which establishes the reference point for the origin of the delay[s]. Then, since since both tPLH and tPHL are specified with respect to the clock edge, and the manufacturer has no clue about what you want to do with his stuff, it's on you to work out, with easy arithmetic, the relative delays.

Comment: There are many circuits whose tolerance for relative delays will be much less than the tolerance for variations in overall delays.  For example, if a device accepts serial input on both rising and falling clock edges, and has a setup time of 100ns and a hold time of -50ns, it would be possible to feed clock and data from two bits of a 74HC373 if both outputs have propagation times of 150ns+/-20ns, or if both have propagation times of 20ns+/-20ns, but not if one output has a delay of 150ns and the other has a propagation time of 20ns.

Comment: In many cases, the factors which would affect the propagation time of one output would affect the propagation time of other outputs similarly, so the worst-case mismatch would be nowhere near as bad as the span between minimum and maximum propagation times.  Unfortunately, manufacturers are often relatively poor about specifying matching characteristics even in cases where it would be totally impractical to build a design which didn't rely upon them [e.g. a lot of logic can guarantee by design that propagation time will always exceed its hold time, and circuits which can rely on that...

Comment: ...can be much simpler, cheaper, and practical that circuits which would need to work even if propagation time was at minimum and hold time was maximum, but for some reason a lot of manufacturers specify a minimum propagation time which is less than the required hold time and offer no guarantee that parts with short propagation time won't have long hold times.]

Comment: @supercat: Your example has very little to do with helping the OP and smacks heavily of your setting up irrelevant twaddle, apparently designed to make it seem like you know what you're talking about. If you'd post a timing diagram or a schematic that'd go a long way to prove me wrong, OK?